# Usage of ～じゃん　for verbs

Tags: usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of ～じゃん (～じゃない)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/usage-of)

usage of ～じゃん　for verbs

Sometimes when i talk to a japanese, they use a lot this. I dont know if there's a rule for it, and when i can or cannot use it.

some examples

> ある**じゃん**
>
> やる**じゃん**
>
> いる**じゃん**
>
> くる**じゃん**
>
> ...

Comment: This is a great question, but any answer to it would apply to your previous question as well (http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/usage-of-for-adjectives).  I would recommend closing this one and editing your other question to ask about the general usage of ～じゃん.