# "jan", "janai", "ne", "desu ne" -- the same more or less?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, colloquial-language, sentence-final-particles, tag-question

I'm trying to understand how to use "jan". **"jan" is a short version of "ja nai", correct?** And it also seems to be almost the same as "ne?" and "desu ne?". Is this correct as well? Can I use them interchangably always?

Comment: I marked this as the *possible* duplicate because I believe the accepted question in the link answers almost all of what OP asked, except the difference between "jan" and "desu ne". But don't you know what "desu" is about?

Comment: If you believe your question was closed unjustifiably, please feel free to edit your question, or at least try to explain why.

Comment: @naruto, it's already edited.

Comment: You mean the bold part? Then did you read [this accepted answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1485/5010), especially the first few sentences and the last paragraph? Again, if you are not satisfied with the existing answer there, please expand your question again and specify the unclear point.