# 良かった vs 良かったじゃない

Tags: adjectives, negation

When I watch an anime, the character to use 良かったじゃない to say something is good, but isn't the word じゃない be a negative expression? Why would it still have the same meaning as 良かった which is the positive version of it?

Comment: Even in English we say "Isn't that nice" don't we?

Comment: but isn't that nice is in a form of question（rhetorical), so it is basically the same idea?

Comment: Yes, the Japanese is in the same format.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1485/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/453/9831

Comment: here「じゃない」actually (more formal) means 「じゃないですか（ではないですか）」and be shortened to 「〜じゃない」。and 「じゃない」means the same as 「でしょ」reference here https://hermes-ir.lib.hit-u.ac.jp/hermes/ir/re/15502/gengo0004100190.pdf